# Non-python tests with a command-line option in pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I'm implementing custom test cases that are based on external files using the tutorial from https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/nonpython.html.

I need to parametrise them with one bool flag. I'd like to be able to run pytest with a commandline option, in my case --use-real-api, which would turn using mocks off and do the real talking to a remote network API.

I've tried using the cmdopt tutorial and blend them together, but can't find any way to read the parameter from within the custom pytest.Item subclass. Could you help? Here is a trivial example from the tutorial. I'd like to get it to change the test behaviour depending on the value of the cmdopt passed.

```
# content of conftest.py
import pytest


def pytest_collect_file(parent, path):
    if path.ext == ".yml" and path.basename.startswith("test"):
        return YamlFile(path, parent)


class YamlFile(pytest.File):
    def collect(self):
        import yaml
        raw = yaml.safe_load(self.fspath.open())
        for name, spec in sorted(raw.items()):
            yield YamlItem(name, self, spec)


class YamlItem(pytest.Item):
    def __init__(self, name, parent, spec):
        super().__init__(name, parent)
        self.spec = spec

    def runtest(self):
        for name, value in sorted(self.spec.items()):
            # some custom test execution (dumb example follows)
            if name != value:
                raise YamlException(self, name, value)

    def repr_failure(self, excinfo):
        """ called when self.runtest() raises an exception. """
        if isinstance(excinfo.value, YamlException):
            return "\n".join(
                [
                    "usecase execution failed",
                    "   spec failed: %r: %r" % excinfo.value.args[1:3],
                    "   no further details known at this point.",
                ]
            )

    def reportinfo(self):
        return self.fspath, 0, "usecase: %s" % self.name


class YamlException(Exception):
    """ custom exception for error reporting. """


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption(
        "--cmdopt", action="store", default="type1", help="my option: type1 or type2"
    )


@pytest.fixture
def cmdopt(request):
    return request.config.getoption("--cmdopt")
```

Comment: Could you elaborate better what do you mean for "parametrize them" please?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this, I've added explanation and my use case.

Comment: For reference: if you're going to have custom non-python tests that accept a command-line argument along with traditional python unit tests in the same project, then py.test executable is going to fail — those standard python tests will complain about unknown command-line argument (unless you call pytest separately for both groups). A way to work this around is to have two conftest.py files — a one with the param definition (cmdop fixture and pytest_addoption definition) in top-level in your test/ directory and the one defining your custom non-python logic in its subdir.

Comment: Thanks for updating the description with further details! By the way, it's a little bit off topic but before implementing non-python YAML based tests in pytest you might consider if you can reuse existing similar plugins that already do the job for you. For example https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-play

Comment: Actually the example was based on YAML because the original example from py.test docs was so. My actual use case is more complex — you write scripts for expected conversation flow with a chatbot, these are text files with user messages, expected bot replies + some extra special lines for config and wildcard assertions. I wanted to make the above case as simple as possible and abstract from details of my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each collection entity in `pytest` (`File`, `Module`, `Function` etc) is a subtype of the [`Node`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#node) class which defines access to the `config` object. Knowing that, the task becomes easy:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--run-yml', action='store_true')

def pytest_collect_file(parent, path):
    run_yml = parent.config.getoption('--run-yml')
    if run_yml and path.ext == ".yml" and path.basename.startswith("test"):
        return YamlFile(path, parent)
```

Running `pytest --run-yml` will now collect the YAML files; without the flag, they are ignored.

Same for accessing the config in custom classes, for example:

```
class YamlItem(pytest.Item):    
    def runtest(self):
        run_yml = self.config.getoption('--run-yml')
        ...
```

etc.